# Swift: How to set size of particle effects with SCNParticleSystem?

Tags: swift, scenekit, particle-system, arkit

I have simple ARKit app (using SceneKit) with cubes floating in space that I am shooting with other objects. I created `.scnp` file with Fire as a template and customized it to sort of look like explosion.

Everything looks good and works on collision, but my whole particle effect takes whole screen. I tried every property available on the `.scnp` file but the size is still enormous.

How can I set the effect area size? For example to be slighty bigger than my cubes (with width 0.1 meters).

This is how run the explosion:

```
let fire = SCNParticleSystem(named: "explosion.scnp", inDirectory: nil)

contactNode.addParticleSystem(fire!)
```

`contactNode` is my target cube.

Answer (score 1):

The particle system property you’re looking for is [`particleSize`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/scenekit/scnparticlesystem/1523508-particlesize). (There’s a control for setting that property in the Xcode particle system GUI editor, but I forget what it’s labeled...)

The docs for that property say:

> The rendered size, in units of the scene’s world coordinate space, of the particle image.

In ARKit, scene units are the same as real-world meters. So while a  particle size of, say, 10x10 might make sense in some arbitrary scene, in AR that makes each particle the size of a house. You probably want values somewhere in the scale of millimeters to centimeters (`0.001` - `0.01`).

Comment: Thanks, that was actually one of the first things I tried. It worked somewhat - particles were smaller but the effect completely changed (instead of one explosion I got something like sparkle). I solved it by trial and error in the end by changing all possible values :-)

Comment: Yeah, *all* of the geometric dimensions that configure a particle system are meter-based (size, speed, etc), so unfortunately there's no easy way to configure a particle system once and then scale the whole thing.